# Assembly - Why do these code chunks different output?

Tags: assembly, x86, stack, nasm

Why do these operations not the same outcome:

```
str db "%d",0

mov eax, 67305985
push eax
push str
call [printf]
pop eax
pop eax
```

Prints 67305985, just as it should

```
str db "%d",0

mov eax, 67305985
mov ebx, eax
shr ebx, 16
mov [esp-1], bh
mov [esp-2], bl
mov ebx, eax
mov [esp-3], bh
mov [esp-4], bl
push str
call [printf]
pop eax
pop eax
```

Prints 1964082724 which I dont understand

Comment: You have to do `sub esp, 4` after the `shr` and then address `esp+3`, `esp+2`, `esp+1` and `esp`.

Comment: In particular, as it stands, `push str` will overwrite the 4 bytes you so carefully stored.

Answer (score 2):

The stack grows downward. The memory below to where `ESP` is pointing can be used freely by all kinds of interruptions.

You need to reserve the memory below `ESP` for your own use. Just subtract 4 from `ESP`.

```
mov eax, 67305985

sub esp, 4
mov [esp], al
mov [esp+1], ah
shr eax, 16
mov [esp+2], al
mov [esp+3], ah
push str
call [printf]
pop eax
pop eax
...
```

If you first store the low bytes, you don't need the extra register.